# Multiple threads accessing the same object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I am building a web server using the `HttpSevlet` in Java. I created an **ABSTRACT** class named **BaseApi** which extends `HttpSevlet` and this serves as the parent class.

Everytime the `doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException` of **BaseApi** is called. a new **BaseRequest** is instantiated. **BaseRequest** is just another class that I created and is a member of **BaseApi**.

```
public abstract class BaseApi extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6333682258528494467L;

    protected BaseRequest request;
}
```

Then I have a child class, **DeviceList** which extends the BaseApi, and **DeviceListRequest** which extends **BaseRequest**

```
public class DeviceList extends BaseApi

public class DeviceListRequest extends BaseRequest
```

The problem is this. Everytime the doGet method of DeviceList is called I **THINK** that a new thread is created. Well, I made 2 concurrent requests and the log looks like this.

```
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,760] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@2f15bbce retCode:-3
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,761] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@5343acea retCode:-3
```

Well, don't mind the retCode thing, just focus on the `Thread:` and `Instance:`. I am not sure if `Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main]` and `Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main]` are two different threads. Because there's a word **MAIN** there. and I don't know if there can be two main threads. Or if this really is the main thread.

So, based on the logs. I think that there are two Threads created and two different instances of **DeviceListRequest** created **DeviceListRequest@2f15bbce** and **DeviceListRequest@5343acea**.

Now, as the code continues to run, I notice that the Threads began to access two **DeviceListRequest** interchangeably. Here's the rest of the logs

```
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,760] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@2f15bbce retCode:-3
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,761] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@5343acea retCode:-3
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,765] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@2f15bbce retCode:0
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,765] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@2f15bbce setResponseObjectWithKey->serverResponse:{"devices":[]} serverResponse_id:636342462
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,765] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@5343acea serverResponse:{"ret_msg":"unknown","ret_code":-3} serverResponse_id:1626294887
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,766] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@5343acea retCode:0
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,766] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@5343acea setResponseObjectWithKey->serverResponse:{"devices":[],"ret_msg":"unknown","ret_code":-3} serverResponse_id:1626294887
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,766] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@5343acea serverResponse:{"devices":[],"ret_msg":"OK","ret_code":0} serverResponse_id:1626294887
```

Again, just look at the Thread: and Instance:

Take a look at this two lines of logs from what I showed

```
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,765] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@2f15bbce setResponseObjectWithKey->serverResponse:{"devices":[]} serverResponse_id:636342462
[2017-10-18 02:06:39,765] INFO  Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main] Instance:server.request.DeviceListRequest@5343acea serverResponse:{"ret_msg":"unknown","ret_code":-3} serverResponse_id:1626294887
```

Thread **Thread:Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main]** accessing objects **DeviceListRequest@2f15bbce** and **DeviceListRequest@5343acea**

NOTES: By the way, I am using `System.identityHashCode(yourObject)` to get the ID of the objects. And I am using `Thread.currentThread()` to get the thread identifier.

My questions are as follows:
1. Are **Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main]** and **Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main]** two different threads?
2. Are threads containing main in their names considered as main thread? If yes, then why there is more than one main thread?
3. How can I avoid the problem that there are threads accessing the objects that were not created on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Are Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-8,5,main] and Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main] two different threads?

Yes, every request is going to run in a different thread.

> 2. Are threads containing main in their names considered as main thread? If yes, then why there is more than one main thread?

No, only the initial thread created on JVM start is considered the main thread. Any thread can be renamed and contain "main" in it's name. The main you see in the log is probably the name of the `ThreadGroup` the actual names of the threads are http-nio-8080-exec-7 and http-nio-8080-exec-8.

> 3. How can I avoid the problem that there are threads accessing the objects that were not created on it?

This is not always a problem, what happens in your case is that you store a `DeviceListRequest` in your Servlet and there is usually only one Servlet which is used for multiple requests. Instead you should use a local variable, pass it to methods if needed or if you're going to forward the request to another Servlet save it in the request.

```
req.setAttribute("someName", new DeviceListRequest());
```

And then when you want to access it later do:

```
req.getAttribute("someName");
```

Answer (score 1):

These are different threads. The servlet container has a Thread pool, threads from the pool will be assigned to http requests. A servlet container is not prohibited from making more than one instance of a given servlet but usually there is only one. You should expect servlets to be called concurrently from multiple threads.

Don't let servlets keep mutable state. Any instance variable that is declared in a servlet should be Thread safe. Making the servlet state relate to a given request is bound to be trouble. Keep state related to a request in local variables of the method.

Comment: Plus one! Thanks for the info!